# ld: library not found for -lAfariaSLL

Tags: iphone, clang

Full error message:

```
    Ld/Users/chairman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Field_Final-dsxytmugnwuntcglfimizlbtmegi/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Field_Final.app/Field_Final normal i386
    cd "/Users/chairman/Documents/Vitthal/NEWFSNOV21_2.3/FSDEVICE2.3 dec6/Field_Final"
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
    setenv PATH "/Users/chairman/Desktop/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Users/chairman/Desktop/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Users/chairman/Desktop/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Users/chairman/Desktop/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk -L/Users/chairman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Field_Final-dsxytmugnwuntcglfimizlbtmegi/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/chairman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Field_Final-dsxytmugnwuntcglfimizlbtmegi/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/chairman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Field_Final-dsxytmugnwuntcglfimizlbtmegi/Build/Intermediates/Field_Final.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Field_Final.build/Objects-normal/i386/Field_Final.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -Objc -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=50100 -framework MapKit -framework CoreLocation -lz.1.2.5 -lstdc++.6 -licucore.A -framework AddressBook -framework CoreFoundation -framework CFNetwork -framework Security -framework MobileCoreServices -framework SystemConfiguration -framework MessageUI -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -lAfariaSLL -lMAKit -lsupUltralite -lsupcore -lSUPObj -lclientrt -lDatavault -lMO -o /Users/chairman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Field_Final-dsxytmugnwuntcglfimizlbtmegi/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Field_Final.app/Field_Final

ld: library not found for -lAfariaSLL
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your target. Under build settings, search for "library search paths". There you should list all the directories where your linked libraries are located.

In respect to SUP, read here about the project settings: http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc01213.0225/doc/html/aro1369255660920.html. The link is for v2.2.5, you can select on the left your version and find the document there.

Comment: I added libraries, tried removing and adding and cleaning and then building app but no luck yet. Anyway Thanks for your valuable and quick reply.

Comment: I tried removing all library search paths and adding also.This both methods also not worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

- Go to targets -> Build phases -> Link Binary With Libraries
- Click on + symbol
- Press Add Other & add your library
- Clean project & than run

Comment: I tried to remove and added again but no luck till now.

Comment: @iVitthal may be project not getting path proper. Do 1 thing Go to targets - build settings - Header Search path Remove old path & than follow above steps.